# How to print flag in page-taxonomy.tpl or in block?

Tags: blocks, theming, 7, flags

I am using the Flag Term module and I am trying to put a flag link in my page-taxonomy.tpl file, because I want the flag positioned in a certain region / block. Having read the documentation it suggest using the flag_create_link function. I added the following code to my page-taxonomy.tpl file:

```
print flag_create_link('like', $term->tid);
```

but it gave:

An HTTP 404 error occurred
http://localhost/drupal/?q=flag/unflag&destination=taxonomy/term/74&toke...

The same thing happens when I try and print the flag in a block. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you can find smth useful from [http://drupal.org/node/1393832](http://drupal.org/node/1393832) .

Comment: Hi thanks, but that was actually me asking the same question on drupal.org, phrased slightly differently